# How to add CAA records, in PowerAdmin(PowerDNS) for ssl certificates in letsencrypt?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, lets-encrypt, caa-record

I am trying to add ssl certificates for a secure connection https for the domain and subdomains, but the problem I get is the following:

DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for DOMAIN
DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for SUBDOMAIN.

Finding out I found that I have to add a new CAA record so that it works for me, but I do not know how to add it.
I currently use powerdns and administer it with poweradmin.

This I must do to fix the previous error:

Domain name: DOMAIN
Record Type: CAA
Value: 0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org"

Basically I have to do this but I do not know how to enter it.

Should I add?

```
Name: DOMAIN
Type: CAA
Content: issuewild "letsencrypt.org"
Priority: 0
TTL: 86400
```

[PowerAdmin Zone IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfdUT.jpg)

PD: For the console does not work, pdnsutil does not work this command does not find it, impossible to add it manually.

Comment: Seems like no one cares about this issue ;) Maybe this link can help you or for anyone that have same problem. https://nordisch.org/posts/more-fun-with-freeipa-and-dns-funky-records/ and more info can be found here : https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/dns/how-to/caa/

Answer (score 0):

The quick and short answer is you add your records as:

```
Name            Type          Content
[[:blank:]]     CAA           0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
*               CAA           0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

[Screen dump caa record for powerdns and poweradmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkQoD.png)

A nice little CAA build helper can be found here: https://sslmate.com/caa/